# macOS Big Sur - Xcode 12.2/12.4 freezing when run any project or .swift file

Tags: xcode12, macos-big-sur

Problem started after update macOS to Big Sur

First of all, I can't update Xcode via Appstore, so I've downloaded from official site 12.4, and it can't open any project or swift file.

What I've tried:

-remove all devices

-change wifi to ethernet

-remove Derived Data and reboot

I've downloaded Xcode 12.2(which was previos for me and worked fine) and install it, still no luck. It just spin and spin, and finally not responding. I am really stuck with this, please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, now I've solved it, so maybe this will help anyone -
based on @dereknahman comment:

```
The issue for me wound up being to do with iCloud. I turned it off and the problem went away. It's a pain, and I haven't found a way to use both at once yet, but it helped!
```

I've moved project from iCloud and all works fine (Big Sur + Xcode 12.4).

Answer (score 0):

For me I deleted all devices connected by network.

then the Xcode stop freezing

**shift + Command + 2**

then delete all connected devices

then try

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it became a continuous pain in 12.3 and 12.4
And thanks God, seems Xcode 12.5 beta fixed this issue

Comment: Have you tried 12.5 beta already? Cause it's little scary for me to update Xcode again after 2 days of finding what was wrong :)

Comment: Yes, I have. It works well. The only issue I see is there is something broken with swipe left-right through the tabs. But it's not freezing anymore - and that is the most important.